# Ubuntu 16.04/Apache 2.4.18: 403 Forbidden

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

Trying to set up a  Minecraft Technic Solder repository on my home server.

Here is my 000-default.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available/:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# Host that will server this project.
ServerName 192.168.1.19
ServerAdmin *email*

# The location of public directory.
DocumentRoot /home/evilarceus/TechnicSolder/public/

# Important options for solder public directory
<Directory /home/evilarceus/TechnicSolder/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/evilarceus/TechnicSolder/public/repo/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Useful logs for debug.
ErrorLog /home/evilarceus/TechnicSolder/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/evilarceus/TechnicSolder/logs/access.log combined
```

The first directory (home/evilarceceus/TechnicSolder/public) works perfectly fine.
However, the second directory (where I want my repo to be) shows 403 Forbidden.

Permissions on repo/:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 evilarceus evilarceus 4096 Oct  2 19:39 repo
```

error.log:

```
[Sun Oct 02 20:39:31.034401 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 17874] [client 192.168.1.20:50072] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/evilarceus/TechnicSolder/public/repo
```

I honestly don't know what to do at this point. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any chance that there's a symlink in there somewhere? If so, what's the FollowSymlinks set to, higher in the hierarchy? (Sometimes, when in doubt, it's sometimes easier to set a wide-open permission higher in the directory structure (or virtualhost hierarchy) and HUP the server - if that fixes it, you know you're dealing with a plain-old permission issue).

Comment: You might also change the "Require all granted" to "Allow from all" and see if that fixes it ... if so, you'll have to dig a little bit deeper in to the "require" for your server version.

Answer (score 2):

Add line `Allow from all` after `Order allow,deny` for directory `/home/evilarceus/TechnicSolder/public/repo/`.

Comment: Hmm, the problem still occurs after that. Instead, it doesn't load the page at all (doesn't even give me the 403). However, if I remove `FollowSymLinks` and use the solution you provided, it loads the page but still gives 403.

Comment: Please show all files in directory `/home/evilarceus/TechnicSolder/public/repo/` and `DirectoryIndex` directive in `httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *very* common problem with using apache configuration files that have both v2.4 auth directives and v2.2 ones.

Find all your old `Allow, Order, Satisfy and Require` directives and change them to the Apache v2.4 `Require` with options `<Require(Any|All|None)>` blocks, and then comment out the loading of mod_access_compat. Otherwise you will continue to have unexpected problems, mostly resulting in `client denied by server configuration`.

Once your config is clean, add any remaining errors.